# inputStream.read returns 1 when not attached to debugger in Cordova Plugin

Tags: android, kotlin, cordova-plugins

I'm having a native Android App which is a RfidScanner. It works fine. But when I import the Kotlin files as a Cordova plugin, it only works when the hardware is connected to the debugger, so when I'm debugging. Could this be a thread issue because the timings are different? Again, it doesn't happen in native Android.

inputStream.read returns 1 without debugger

inputStream.read returns 13 with debugger (=correct)

- The [documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/plugin.html) explicitly mentions using the `ExecutorService` for running background threads.

  fun start() {
  _isRunning = true
  cordovaInterface.threadPool.submit {
  try {
  Log.d("JIM", "executorService.submit ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
  while (_isRunning) {
  Thread.sleep(100)
  Log.d("JIM", "Thread.sleep(100) inside")
  val buffer = ByteArray(256)
  try {
  val available = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, buffer.size)
  Log.d("JIM", "inputStream.read(buffer")
  if (available > 0) {
  val data = ByteArray(available)
  System.arraycopy(buffer, 0, data, 0, available)

  ```
                        Log.d("JIM", "available = $available > data = ${data.size}")
                        process(data)
                    }
                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    Log.d("JIM", "Exception")
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            Log.d("JIM", "Exception")
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }
    Log.d("JIM", "Thread.sleep(100) before send ${Thread.currentThread().name}")
    send(_scanCommand)
  ```

  }

Without debugger:

```
2021-01-11 18:39:18.125 8836-8836/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: Thread.sleep(100) before send main
2021-01-11 18:39:18.125 8836-8899/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: executorService.submit pool-1-thread-1
2021-01-11 18:39:18.125 8836-8836/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: send [B@a8fa829
2021-01-11 18:39:18.225 8836-8899/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: Thread.sleep(100) inside
2021-01-11 18:39:18.226 8836-8899/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: inputStream.read(buffer
2021-01-11 18:39:18.226 8836-8899/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: available = 1 > data = 1
2021-01-11 18:39:18.226 8836-8899/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: data != null
2021-01-11 18:39:18.226 8836-8899/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: byte data size = 1
2021-01-11 18:39:18.226 8836-8899/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: send [B@a8fa829
2021-01-11 18:39:18.327 8836-8899/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: Thread.sleep(100) inside
2021-01-11 18:39:19.353 8836-8836/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: 4. onStopScan
```

With debugger (available = 13 and this is correct):

```
2021-01-11 18:39:54.185 9013-9013/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: Thread.sleep(100) before send main
2021-01-11 18:39:54.185 9013-9084/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: executorService.submit pool-1-thread-1
2021-01-11 18:39:55.262 9013-9013/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: send [B@3f1554d
2021-01-11 18:39:57.009 9013-9084/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: Thread.sleep(100) inside
2021-01-11 18:39:57.009 9013-9084/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: inputStream.read(buffer
2021-01-11 18:39:59.060 9013-9084/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: available = 13 > data = 13
2021-01-11 18:39:59.723 9013-9084/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: data != null
2021-01-11 18:39:59.723 9013-9084/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: byte data size = 13
2021-01-11 18:40:00.096 9013-9084/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: byte data size = 13
2021-01-11 18:40:00.532 9013-9084/nl.rfidscanner D/JIM: byte != 0.toByte()
```

Comment: `_isRunning` is always `true`... and it's unknown what `inputStream` even is (which is most likely the cause of the problem).

Comment: have you read what the problem is?